# Django rest Framework: How to create a custom, auto-generating string field?

Tags: python, django

I'm using the generic Django Rest Framework classes for an application, but I'd like to be able to auto-generate a short customer order ID whenever a new order instance is created.

The generic classes are awesome, but small tweaks can get messy fast. I'm wondering if there's a way to do the auto-generation in `models.py`, in the spirit of classes like `AutoIncrement` or the way the primary key integer is created (but not as a primary key).

Let's say I have a model

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    details = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)

    @property
    def title(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name}'s, order"
```

and I want to add a new field, `order_reference`. And lets say I want to add some custom logic, like

```py
@before_createish_thing
def order_reference(self):
    # Return something like XYZ2021-000-23
    return f"XYZ-{datetime.now().year}-000-{self.order_id}"
```

somewhere.

I don't suppose there's anything like a `before_create` decorator along the same lines as the `@property` decorator?

My view is as simple as

```py
class OrderList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer
```

hence my reluctance to hack it apart just to get to the `create()` method.

Is there any way to do this, ideally by somehow placing the logic in the model file?

Comment: what about adding a `creation_date` DateField in your model and use this in your property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply do something like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    details = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=200)
    creation_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def title(self):
        return f"{self.user.first_name}'s, order"

    @property
    def order_reference(self):
        return f"XYZ-{self.creation_date.year}-000-{self.order_id}"
```

Also storing the date can allow you to change later your order_reference property and have access to the day, month, year for example. Or even use a DatetimeField. It always good to have the creation date, for future requirements.

Comment: I like it, it's a nice solution. Using a datetime was actually just an example, but why not? Definitely works.